# Let $\gamma(t) = 2e^{it}$ for $-\pi \le t \le \pi$. I am looking for an explanation for the way $\int_{\gamma}(z^{2} - 1)^{-1} dz$ is evaluated below.

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is a problem from Conway's Functions of One Complex Variable. Let $\gamma(t) = 2e^{it}$ for $-\pi \le t \le \pi$. The problem asks to evaluate $\int_{\gamma}(z^{2} - 1)^{-1} dz$.

The solution I have says that because $T(z)=\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ preserves $\mathbb{R}_{\infty}$, then $T(z)$ is in $\mathbb{R}_{\le 0} \cup \{\infty\}$ iff $z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $-1 \le z \le 1$. How can I see that the iff statement is true?

The solution then goes on to say that this means that away from that interval and in particular, on an open set containing $\gamma$, we have that $\log \frac{z-1}{z+1}$ is well-defined. I don't exactly see how the logic for log being well-defined follows either and would appreciate if someone can provide an explanation. How can we be away from the interval $-1 \le z \le 1$ when it's inside $\gamma$?

After all of this, the solution is that $\frac{1}{2} \log \frac{z-1}{z+1}$ is a primitive of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^{2}-1}$, so the integral around the closed curve $\gamma$ will be $0$.

Comment: You may want to modify the title to better describe the question: the former suggests this is a problem of integration, but the latter makes clear that you’re really asking about properties of $z\mapsto (z-1)/(z+1)$.

Comment: The intuition for that specific line is that the negative reals are often excluded from the domain of $\log$ (the principal branch for example). The solution chose that particular $T$ because it (a) takes each pole and maps it to $0$ and "$\infty$" and (b) maps the line segment between the two poles to that special  ray with a bijection on (almost all of) $\Bbb{C}$. This means we can ascribe a branch of $\log$ to the domain, i.e. $\log T(z)$ can be well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so much easier to observe the following two things: both poles, $\pm1$, of the integrand are enclosed by the contour with positive orientation, and we can compute the residues at each pole with L'Hopital's rule (they are simple poles) by: $$\frac{1}{2z}\Big|_{z=\pm1}=\pm\frac{1}{2}$$Because the signs are opposite, the sum of residues is zero. So, the integral is zero.

---

Anyway. Say $z=\sigma+i\tau$ has ($\sigma,\tau\in\Bbb R$) $T(z)\in(\Bbb R_{\le0}\cup\{\infty\})$. We want to show this occurs when and only when $\tau=0,\sigma\in[-1,1]$.

$T(z)=\infty$ means exactly that $z=-1$, just because that's the only pole. In the other case, $T(z)\in\Bbb R$, we can compute: $$\frac{z-1}{z+1}=\frac{(\sigma-1)+i\tau}{(\sigma+1)+i\tau}=\frac{(\sigma^2-1+\tau^2)+2i\tau}{(\sigma+1)^2+\tau^2}$$This is real iff. the imaginary part is zero, iff. $\tau=0$. Then, the real part is $\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma+1}$, which is asked to be nonpositive. It's easy to see that is true iff. $\sigma\in(-1,1]$.  The claim is true.

Now, let's use $\log$ to denote the *principal* logarithm, which is holomorphic on $\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R_{\le0}$. So, $z\mapsto\log\frac{z-1}{z+1}=\log T(z)$ is holomorphic at $z$ if and only if $T(z)$ is finite and not in $\Bbb R_{\le0}$, that is, if and only if $z\in\Bbb C\setminus[-1,1]$ by the claim.

So, on $\Bbb C\setminus[-1,1]$, we can see that $$z\mapsto\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{z-1}{z+1}$$Is a primitive of $z\mapsto(z^2-1)^{-1}$.

Are there open sets containing the (trace of) $\gamma$ that avoid $[-1,1]$? Yes, there are. For example, the annulus: $$\{z\in\Bbb C:\frac{3}{2}<|z|<\frac{5}{2}\}$$

$[-1,1]$ is "contained" in $\gamma$ in the sense that it is *enclosed* by the contour, but it is not a literal subset of $\gamma$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clearly explained answer. Helped a lot!

Comment: @JohnSmith You’re very welcome